# What is injected to UseAuthorization Middleware from AddAuthentication Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I Have a controller called Home and it contain 3 methods.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Secret()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Authenticate()
        {

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
```

and in my ConfigureServices ,i have this code:

```
 services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth")
       .AddCookie("CookieAuth", config => {
             config.Cookie.Name = "Ali.Cookie";
             config.LoginPath = "/Home/Authenticate";
        });
```

and in my Configure,i have this code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
```

Now my question is, What is injected to UseAuthorization Middleware from AddAuthentication Service? and how that happened ?

Answer (score 5):

`UseAuthorization` is adding  authorization middleware to application . If the app doesn't use authorization, you can safely remove the call to `app.UseAuthorization()`.

If you want to use Authorization feature (e.g. `Authorize` attribute or other code) , then `app.UseAuthorization()` is needed  , and apply Authorize attribute on controller/action  means the controller/action requires a signed in user , if user is not authenticated , the authentication schema  "CookieAuth" fires which will redirect user to default login page for sign in . But the problem of your code is `UseAuthentication` should add before the `UseAuthorization` middleware , otherwise authentication won't work and user may face infinite loop to your login method :

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();  <-- add this line 
app.UseAuthorization();
```

You can check [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authorization) for more details .

Comment: thank you for your answer but my question is, how ```services.AddAuthentication``` work exactly?

Comment: Please check document firstly : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1