# Is either AddAuthentication and AddAuthorization required if UseIdentityServer is present?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#startup-class), we have that

> The authentication middleware that is responsible for validating the request credentials and setting the user on the request context `app.UseAuthentication()`
> The IdentityServer middleware that exposes the OpenID Connect endpoints `app.UseIdentityServer()`

However, checking the latter method declaration, I see the following, which appears to me that it's unnecessary to invoke the former.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseIdentityServer(
  this IApplicationBuilder app,
  IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions options = null)
{
    app.Validate();
    app.UseMiddleware<BaseUrlMiddleware>();
    app.ConfigureCors();
    if (options == null) options = new IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions();
    options.AuthenticationMiddleware(app);
    app.UseMiddleware<MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<IdentityServerMiddleware>();
    return app;
}
```

I see nothing about `UseAuthorization`, though. So my conclusion is that the general approach presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61378240/1525840) (i.e. first authentication, then authorization), may be reformulated in my case to the following. While I can (should?) skip the second line, I can't remove the third (since I'm using e.g. `[Authorize]` attribute in the project).

```
builder.UseIdentityServer();
//builder.UseAuthentication();
builder.UseAuthorization();
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `UseAuthentication()` part, as that is already added by `UseIdentityServer()` under the hood as you mentioned in the question.

But you need to keep the `UseAuthorization()` part.

Comment: Very clear and precise answer. I took the liberty to style up the code parts. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Is there a link to the source code where `UseAuthentication` added by `UseIdentityServer`?

Comment: Never mind, found it [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/5bcc2abbcf6c47200c4eb3b77e756f1bc0e04358/src/IdentityServer4/src/Configuration/IdentityServerMiddlewareOptions.cs#L12)